# Drawing to existing PDF

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

When i did `CGContextCreateWithURl(url)` it created empty context even though i passed url of existing file. How to get the context of existing PDF file?

Comment: How do you create your `url` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you can't actually draw directly to an existing pdf:

1. Convert pdf to image
2. Draw new content to that image
3. Convert appended image to pdf

Not the smoothest, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

the URL isn't an input. It's where you want the context to write the resulting PDF to.

From the documentation:

> *url*
>     A Core Foundation URL that specifies where you want to place the resulting PDF file.